# Can you use .Find to search if a cell contains part of a string?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the .Find function to find two strings and determine which row they are in. For this example the two strings that I am looking for are "Wavelength" and "Test-Config" as shown in the rowindex = getrowindex(sysnum, "Wavelength", "Test-Config") line. For this case it works fine, however, for my next line `rowindex_1 = getrowindex(sysnum, "Wavelength Range", "ModTst,FunctionalTest,ShpPrp")` I want to use `.Find` to see the row that has column B value of "Wavelength Range" and column C that contains `"FunctionalTest"` without having the have the full `"ModTst,FunctionalTest,ShpPrp"` be included as the input string to the function `getrowindex`

I have attached all my code. It currently can run up until  `rowindex_1 = getrowindex(sysnum, "Wavelength Range", "ModTst,FunctionalTest,ShpPrp")` which it stops at since in Column C there is no cell value of `ModTst,FunctionalTest,ShpPrp` as it is case sensitive. However, I want it to still go ahead and say if column C cell value = `FunctionalTest` then find that row index with `Wavelength Range` and `FunctionalTest`

```
Public Sub Main()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, dict As Object, sysrow As Integer, sysnum As String, wsName As String
Dim wbSrc As Workbook, SDtab As Worksheet
Dim colindex As Long
Dim spectyp As Long, specmin As Long, specmax As Long
Dim sweep_value As Double, sweep_value_max As Double
Dim rowindex As Double, rowindex_1 As Double

Dim Value As Double
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet 

Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("Q:Specification and Configuration Document.xlsx")
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In ws.Range("E2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Cells
    sysnum = cell.Value
    sysrow = cell.Row
    syscol = cell.Column

    If sysnum = "" Then
    MsgBox "No WD number, skipping to next row."
    GoTo Skip
    End If
If Not dict.Exists(sysnum) Then 
    dict.Add sysnum, True
    If Not SheetExists(sysnum, ThisWorkbook) Then
        wsName = cell.EntireRow.Columns("D").Value 
        If SheetExists(wsName, wbSrc) Then 
            wbSrc.Worksheets(wsName).Copy after:=ws 
            wb.Worksheets(wsName).name = sysnum 
        Set SDtab = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Index + 1) 
            Debug.Print SDtab.name
            
        End If

spectyp = getcolumnindex(SDtab, "Spec Typical") 
specmin = getcolumnindex(SDtab, "SPEC min")
specmax = getcolumnindex(SDtab, "SPEC max")

 Sheets(1).Select 

' Wavelength Tuning Range Section
colindex = getcolumnindex(ws, "Tuning Range (nm)")
Value = getjiradata(ws, sysrow, colindex) ' wavelength tuning range value
rowindex = getrowindex(sysnum, "Wavelength Range", "Test-Config-OCT")
rowindex_1 = getrowindex(sysnum, "Wavelength Range", "ModTst,FunctionalTest,ShpPrp")

End Sub
```

---

```
Function getrowindex(WDnum As Variant, parametername As String, routingname As String)
Dim parameter_row As Range, ws As Worksheet, rowname As Range, addr As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WDnum)
Set rowname = ws.Columns("B").Find(What:=parametername, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True) 

If Not rowname Is Nothing Then 
        addr = rowname.Address 
    Do
        If rowname.Offset(0, 1).Value = routingname Then 
            getrowindex = rowname.Row
            Exit Do 
        End If
        Set rowname = ws.Columns("B").FindNext(after:=rowname)
    Loop While rowname.Address <> addr 
End If
End Function
```

UPDATE:

```
Function getrowindex(WDnum As String, parametername As String, routingname As String, Optional partialFirst As Boolean = False, Optional partialSecond As Boolean = False) 
Dim ws As Worksheet, rowname As Range, addr As String, copy As Long, Output As Integer, rngParam As Range, rngRouting As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WDnum)

Set rowname = ws.Columns(Parameter).Find(What:=parametername, Lookat:=IIf(partialFirst, xlPart, xlWhole), LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True) 

If Not rowname Is Nothing Then ' check that parametername can be found
    addr = rowname.Address 
    If partialSecond Then routingname = "*" & routingname & "*" 
    Do
        If rowname.EntireRow.Columns(RoutingStep).Value Like routingname Then ' check column C for cell with routingname
            If rngParam Is Nothing Then 
                Set rngParam = ws.Range(rowname, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, Parameter))
                Set rngRouting = rngParam.EntireRow.Columns(RoutingStep)
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rngParam, parametername, rngRouting, routingname) > 1 Then ' counts the number of cells within given range that meet multiple criteria (in this case that have parametername and routingname)
                    MsgBox "This row combination of " & parametername & " and " & routingname & _
                           " appears in multiple lines. Check before running again.", vbCritical ' prints if there a multiple rows with same case sensitive name
                    Stop
                End If
            End If
            
            getrowindex = rowname.Row ' row index for the combination of parameter and routing step
            Exit Do
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Row combination " & parametername & " and " & routingname & " cannot be found. Check before running again.", vbCritical
        Stop
       End If

        Set rowname = ws.Columns(Parameter).FindNext(After:=rowname)
    Loop While rowname.Address <> addr ' loop back to check find operation for parametername
Else ' else if parametername row cannot be found send message
    MsgBox parametername & " row could not be found. Check before running again.", vbCritical
    Stop
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this (added a couple of parameters to control whether exact or partial match is used).  Match type defaults to exact.

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim rnum As Long
    
    'exact match on both "Wavelength Range" and "FunctionalTest"
    rnum = getrowindex("Sheet1", "Wavelength Range", "FunctionalTest")

    'exact match on "Wavelength Range", partial match on "FunctionalTest"
    rnum = getrowindex("Sheet1", "Wavelength Range", "FunctionalTest", _
                       partialSecond:=True)
    
    'partial match on "Wavelength Range", exact match on "FunctionalTest"
    rnum = getrowindex("Sheet1", "Wavelength Range", "FunctionalTest", _
                       partialFirst:=True)

    'partial match on "Wavelength Range" and "FunctionalTest"
    rnum = getrowindex("Sheet1", "Wavelength Range", "FunctionalTest", _
                       partialFirst:=True, partialSecond:=True)
    
    
    Debug.Print rnum

End Sub


'Find the row number on sheet `WDnum` where ColB matches `parametername` and
'  ColC matches `routingname`.  Use exact or partial match based on optional parameters
'  `partialFirst` and `partialSecond`
Function getrowindex(WDnum As Variant, parametername As String, routingname As String, _
                     Optional partialFirst As Boolean = False, Optional partialSecond As Boolean = False)
    Dim parameter_row As Range, ws As Worksheet, rowname As Range, addr As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WDnum)
    Set rowname = ws.Columns("B").Find(What:=parametername, _
        Lookat:=IIf(partialFirst, xlPart, xlWhole), LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
    
    If Not rowname Is Nothing Then
            addr = rowname.Address
            If partialSecond Then routingname = "*" & routingname & "*"
        Do
            If rowname.Offset(0, 1).Value Like routingname Then
                getrowindex = rowname.Row
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set rowname = ws.Columns("B").FindNext(after:=rowname)
        Loop While rowname.Address <> addr
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I think using `Like` is the correct move, however, it is not detecting the partial string match. For line `rowindex_1 = getrowindex(sysnum, "Wavelength Tuning Range", "FunctionalTest")` I am searching for cells with Column B of "Wavelength Range" and Column C of "FunctionalTest" When in Column C the row 276 which is what rowindex_1 should equal has a value of `ModTst,FunctionalTest,ShpPrp`

Comment: "Wavelength Tuning Range" will not match "Wavelength Range".

Comment: Column B should be `"Wavelength Tuning Range"` What the code cannot do is find the input partial string of `"FunctionalTEst"` within the cell value of `"ModTst,FunctionalTest,ShpPrp"`

Comment: Exactly how are you calling the function?  Are you passing `partialSecond:=True` as shown in my example usage?

Comment: Oh I had excluded the partialFirst section. What does `Find(What:=parametername, Lookat:=IIf(partialFirst, xlPart, xlWhole)` mean and why is `routingname` used twice in this line `If partialSecond Then routingname = "*" & routingname & "*"`

Comment: The use of `IIf()` is just an in-line way of  doing soemthing like `If partialFirst = True Then Lookat=xlPart Else Lookat=xlWhole`  Adding the `*` to `routingname` is so the `Like` can use it to look for a partial match (without any wildcards, `Like` works like `=`)

Comment: Oh okay so if the parametername for partialFirst can be determined, then it will look for a partial match for routingname, else it will look for an exact match of routingname?

Comment: `parametername` is "first" and `routingname` is "second" - `partialFirst` determines if an exact or partial match is used for `parametername`, and `partialSecond` controls the same logic for `routingname`

Comment: Is there a way to go about this with just using `partialSecond` I need `parametername` to be an exact match not just a partial match

Comment: `parametername` is always an exact match unless you pass in `partialFirst:=True`

Comment: Is there possibly a link on how this logic works? I see in the function it is defined as `partialFirst As Boolean = False` and if I have to pass it in in order to make it a partial match, wouldnt I have to have `partialSecond:=True` then?

Comment: Both parameters are Optional, which means you can pass in either, both or neither of them, and they both have a default value of `False`, so the default behavior for `getrowindex` is to search for an exact match on both terms.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/optional-parameters

Comment: I see, but no where in my code do I see it set `partialSecond:=True` to make its value `True` for partial match

Comment: Well if you don't pass `partialSecond:=True` then it will use exact match.

Comment: I based my code off the answer you provided. I updated what I am working with. would I be able to write `partialSecond:=True` before line ` If partialSecond Then routingname = "*" & routingname & "*"`

Comment: The behavior of `getrowindex` depends entirely on *how you call it* (ie. whether you pass True for either `patialFirst` or `partialSecond`.  I'm not understanding the problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: An example of how it is being called from `Sub Main` is `rowindex = getrowindex(sysnum, "Wavelength Range", "Test-Config-OCT")`

Comment: If you call it like that then it will perform an exact match on both terms.

Comment: Ohhh but for `wavelength_rowindex_1 = getrowindex(sysnum, "Wavelength Tuning Range", "SYS-FunctionalTest-OCT", partialSecond:=True)` it will perform a partial match on both terms. Is there a way for it to perform an exact match on "Wavelength Tuning Range" but a partial match on "SYS-FunctionalTest-OCT"?

Comment: See my updated example code above.

Comment: I tried that, but now it is skipping the whole `If Not rowname Is Nothing Then ...` and going straight to the `Else
            MsgBox "Row combination " & parametername & " and " & routingname & " cannot be found. Check before running again.", vbCritical` when there is in fact a row combination of the two variables when I go and debug

Comment: This probably needs a new question, with minimal code to reproduce the problem, and some sample data showing what you're searching against...